# dropzone.js events callback object structure

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I would like to know what is hidden inside `file` variable in that code:

`this.on("complete", function(file) { alert("Added file."); });`

What is the structure of that object? I did not found this in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try a regular console.log(file); before alert("Added file.");

Then press F12 to get the development tools and look at the console output

Comment: Thanks I will try.